# D3 - Axis with dates

Tags: d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/FOsIWASEDLHhypatomrt?p=preview

Its very basic, I'm just trying to create the axis

The data will be in the format thats in the plunker

I'd the y axis to be from 0 to the highest figure in the data.

The x axis should be the dates.

```
chart.append('g')
  .classed('x axis', true)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d")))

chart.append('g')
  .classed('y axis', true)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
    .ticks(10));
```

I cant get either axis to work - can anyone help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your time scale, you need to convert your strings into date objects, the most simple way would be to define your scale as:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { 
    return new Date(d.date); 
  }))
  .range([0, width]);
```

While for your y axis, the issue is in how you define your scale domain. Your data is in the form:

```
var data = [
   {
      "one":4306,
      "two":2465,
      "three":2299,
      "four":988,
      "five":554,
      "six":1841,
      "date":"2015-05-31T00:00:00"
   },
```

But your scale domain is set with:

```
.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
    return d;
  })
```

`d` here is an object, with properties listed above. You can set it to the max of one of those properties:

```
.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
    return d.one;
  })
```

Or with a bit of modification, to the overall highest:

```
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
    var a = [d.one,d.two,d.three,d.four,d.five,d.six]; // properties to check
    return d3.max(a);  // overall max
    })])
```

Here's a snippet showing your axes in action:

```js
let keys = [];
let legendKeys = [];

var w = 800;
var h = 450;

var margin = {
  top: 30,
  bottom: 40,
  left: 50,
  right: 20,
}

var width = w - margin.left - margin.right
var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom

var colors = [
  '#FFEBB6','#FFC400','#B4EDA0','#FF4436','#FF9A00'];

var data = [
   {
      "one":4306,
      "two":2465,
      "three":2299,
      "four":988,
      "five":554,
      "six":1841,
      "date":"2015-05-31T00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "one":4378,
      "two":2457,
      "three":2348,
      "four":1021,
      "five":498,
      "six":1921,
      "date":"2015-06-30T00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "one":3404,
      "two":2348,
      "three":1655,
      "four":809,
      "five":473,
      "six":1056,
      "date":"2015-07-31T00:00:00"
   },
]

legendKeys = ['New', 'Used']

var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { 
    return new Date(d.date); 
  }))
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
    var a = [d.one,d.two,d.three,d.four,d.five,d.six];
    return d3.max(a)
    })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('class', 'chart')
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);

var chart = svg.append('g')
  .classed('graph', true)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
  
  
chart.append('g')
  .classed('x axis', true)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d")).tickValues(data.map(function(d) { return new Date(d.date)}) ))
    ;

chart.append('g')
  .classed('y axis', true)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
    .ticks(10));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks but I was expecting 3 date on the x axis - 2015-05-31, 2015-06-30, 2015-07-31

Comment: If you want a tick for each value in the data array, then you could use something like : `.tickValues(data.map(function(d) { return new Date(d.date)})` which will assign a tick for each date in the data array. I've updated the snippet to demonstrate.